# Alarm preventing activity from finish

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I am using Alarm service in an Android application and here is the code snippet for same

**Creation of Pending Intent**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UninstallService.class);
intent.putExtra("APPLICATION_PREFERENCE", applicationPreference);
intent.setAction(intentAction);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,
    intentRequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

**Scheduling of an Alarm**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
```

After scheduling the alarm, I invoke `finish` on Activity, but the activity doesn't finish. It stays open and there is no clue what is happening. If I comment the call to `set` method on AlarmManager and invoke `finish` on Activity, the activity is closed.

This is bit weird and I am not sure, what I am missing. Please help.

**Android OS** : Lollipop (5.0.2 - API 21)

Comment: Are you invoking `finish()` from the same activity?

Comment: Yes, I am invoking `finish()` from same activity. The application has just one activity. Is it because the lifecycle of service is tied up to Activity's context?

Comment: Can you post the activity code how you doing

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UninstallService.class);
intent.setAction(intentAction);
intent.putExtra("APPLICATION_PREFERENCE", applicationPreference);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

alarmMgr .setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent );
```